# Vertical Menu w/ Hidden Sub Menus

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I have built this Vertical Menu with hidden submenus however I cannot get the submenu to display when the user hovers. How could I go about doing this? Also how can I get the text to be formatted all the way left, since they are lists I can get rid of the bullets, however I cannot get the text to go where the bullets used to be. Also, I am wondering what the best way would be to set the width of the "main-nav". I don't want anything to be over the text except the logo. The body of the site would be next to the navigation. I want the side of the logo to also line up with the left side of the text, and I cannot figure out how to do this. The red border is just for testing purposes (obviously).

Here is the link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/jAvzEA).

[BONUS] I am trying to create my own site from scratch with wordpress and a custom theme. How does one create it so that the logo image is taken from the site identity tab in the customize sidebar? And also just display text if no logo is chosen in the identity bar. Would it be some wordpress php function? Also, I would want the logo to be apart of the main-navigation by default. I have the register_nav_menu() function in my functions.php file and it assigns a menu to Main Navigation, also giving it a class main-navigation. How could I get the logo to by default appear above this menu? Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated. (Wordpress/coding noob here)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" class="logo-branding" />
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-navigation {
    bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 15%;
}

.main-navigation li, .main-navigation a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font: 16pt helvetica, sans serif;
    padding: 1%;
}

.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation .active {
    color: tan !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.main-navigation .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.main-navigation .sub-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}

#container {
    height: 10000px;
}

.logo-branding {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 8%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 15%;
}
```

JS:

```
/* No JS */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBJWmm?editors=1100) is your desired behaviour?

To do this, you need to place your ul submenu *inside* the li for the menu item that is displayed. This is the only change I made to the HTML.

You can then add a CSS rule so that when you hover over the `li`, its `ul` child becomes visible. i.e: `.main-navigation li:hover {display: block; }`.

The reason it didn't work when you did `.main-navigation .sub-menu:hover` is because when it is not being displayed, you cannot hover over it, so the hover state is never triggered. In the rule which I added, it is triggered when you hover over the containing `li`.

```css
.main-navigation {
  bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15%;
}
.main-navigation li,
.main-navigation a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font: 16pt helvetica, sans serif;
  padding: 1%;
}
.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation .active {
  color: tan !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.main-navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#container {
  height: 10000px;
}
.logo-branding {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 8%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" class="logo-branding" />
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu v</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

---

**EDIT:** I may have made a mistake regarding WordPress, so I deleted that part of the answer so that I do not mislead anyone. E. Shio, however, found a [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo) which explains it almost step by step. I'll summarise what this link says, just in case it someday gets deleted or the page url gets moved.

First, you check if there is a custom logo, for which you use `has_custom_logo ()`. You then output that custom logo with `the_custom_logo()`. This is a relatively new feature to Wordpress though, so to maintain backwards compatibility, you should check if the function exists with `function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' )`. If there was no custom logo, you can output the text to display inside an else statement. Here's an example:

```
if( function_exists('the_custom_logo') ) {
    if( has_custom_logo() ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    } else {
        $blogname = get_bloginfo('name');
        echo "<h1>$blogname</h1>";
    }
}
```

---

If you have any questions about the CSS for the menu, I'm more than happy to help! (I'm no expert in Wordpress though, so I probably can't help with any Wordpress specific things, but I can try! XP)

Comment: Is there anyway to add a transition (or at least slow the transition) for when the menu moves up to make room for the submenus?

Comment: Hiya, no problem! Here's it animated http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akaGpZ?editors=1100#anon-login To animate it, I changed the `display: none` to `max-height: 0`, and `opacity: 0`, as display is not an animatable property, but these are. Now it will animate the growth of the box and fade in the text. You can ask me if you don't understand how it works ☺. Also I changed the width to 100% because I was on my phone & it was too small to hover over. You can change its width back to the original.

Comment: Also about the logo, yeah I think the functions I mentioned were for a different type of icon. I'll delete that part of the answer & put your link. I don't want to mislead anyone xP

Comment: Yeah, that works great. How would you recommend making it more versatile for if I add more items? (instead of 500px) Also I made it so that instead of hovering over it to open you have to click on it and be on that page, but it doesn't stay open on the page? How do I make it so it stays open on that page? Check out the originial codepen link :P

Comment: I got the highlight working for each page when active!

Comment: When you use the opacity trick, it just moves the links down and covers the other menu items so they can no longer be selected.

Comment: Also to target the logo and have it display you target, "the_custom_logo"

Comment: Hiya, great to see that you've got it figured out! In response to whether you should increase the `max-height`, since you are developing a theme and you are unsure how many sub items people will add, it is a good idea to add some overhead. Just be wary that the greater the value you put for the max height, the quicker the animation will be, as it will still have 2 seconds to grow a large amount. So you should add a reasonable amount of overhead, and also increase the transition duration.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using jQuery if you changed it to work on click. jQuery has functions which will handle this animation for you. Good luck! Do you have any further questions or have you figured everything out already?

Comment: How could I pm you to show you the product? I am running into some issues lol I decided to scrap the animation for theme sake which is okay and looks good for now but I cannot get the image to align properly. I have a new thread started if you want to check it out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119047/discussion-between-xhaerithius-and-e-shio).

Comment: jQuery is an option however I want it to run as fast as possible and be super minimal and not take to much juice to run. :P